# Assign class to list item on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, addclass, removeclass

I am trying to add a class "current" to a clicked list item (only "About" and "Events", not the sub-menu items which are actual links -- "About" and "Events" don't go anywhere) and, when another list item is clicked, add the class "current" to the newly clicked item and remove it from the previously clicked item. This code almost works, but it takes two clicks to make the switch-- the first item keeps the current class through the first click and the second item receives it on the second click. Any ideas on how I can get this down to a one-click action would be greatly appreciated. Here's the HTML:

```js
jQuery('li').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="current">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <div class="submenu second about-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link1">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="link2">Link2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</div>
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Events</a>
  <div class="submenu second events-menu">
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
</li>
</div>
</li>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$('li')` will match both the top-level LIs and the inner LIs. You need a more specific selector if you want it to work just on the top-level ones.

Comment: It seems to work with a single click when I try it.

Comment: Your code is working - question is - do you need just top level LI's highlighted?

Comment: you don't need to use href in the a tag, use name or class instead.

Comment: Thank you -- yes -- see below, I really appreciate your looking at this as I now realize the problem is a script conflict. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a class `topLevel` to the main `<li>` items just to differentiate them (About, Event).

When an `<li>` item is clicked first remove the current class from all top level items `jQuery('.topLevel').removeClass('current');`, then check if the list item is a top level list, directly add the `current` class to it, otherwise add it to the closest top level list.

I hope this is what you need:

```js
jQuery('li').click(function() {

   jQuery('.topLevel').removeClass('current');

   if(jQuery(this).hasClass('topLevel'))
   {
     jQuery(this).addClass('current');
   }
   else
   {
       jQuery(this).closest('topLevel').addClass('current');
   }
});
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="topLevel current">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <div class="submenu second about-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</div>
</li>
<li  class="topLevel"> <a href="#">Events</a>
  <div class="submenu second events-menu">
    <ul>
      ...
    </ul>
</li>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much -- this is my first post on StackOverflow and I am so grateful for the response!  So what you gave me does work and led me to the actual problem with the double-click issue, which is a conflict with another script that is running on the site (popr.js). So I will delve into that. Thanks again!